# Python post method with requests

Tags: python, post, request

I'm trying to login to website using request in Python 3.
Unfortunately I am unable to do it.

This is information I get from login request:

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer:fffff
```

Request Payload:

```
{email: "xxx", password: "yyy", _token: "zzz"}
```

My code:

```
with requests.Session() as x:
    url = 'website'
    USERNAME = "xxx"
    PASSWORD = "yyy"
    token = "zzz"
    x.get(url)
    x.post(url, data={'email': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWORD, '_token':token},
           headers={'Referer':"fffff"})
    page = x.get("some_page_I_have_access_after_login")
    print(page.content)
```

The only result for last 'print' is 'Please log in to....'

Can you please help me with that?

edit:

I have change code to:

```
url = 'url'
USERNAME = "xxx"
PASSWORD = "yyy"
token = "fff"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Referer':'cccc'}
data = {'email': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWORD, '_token':token}
x = requests.get(url)
w = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(w.status_code)
page = requests.get("some_url_I_want_access")
page.raise_for_status()
```

Now I have clear status.
For w (login action) I have status 200. 
And there is a problem, because when I have changed my username I still got 200 so that means that I am unable to log in.

For page I got: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: "some_url_I_want_access"

Comment: Are you sure you can send credentials using JSON? Usually it is sent with form encoding.

Comment: I don't know that, but what is weird is that I have changed line x.post(....) to w = x.post(...) and add line print(w.content) in next line. It seems that I am logged in because I get html of my_page then. Unfortunately I still get the same error for last "print" statement.

Comment: Ok I've made a progres. I think that I know where mistake is. When I run my program, request body is: email=aaa%40ccc.com&_token=xxx&password=yyy   But when I insepct working-browser request, request body is: {"email":"aaa@ccc.com","password":"yyy","_token":"xxx"} It's not exactly the same and when I copy-paste this line from working request and paste it into web debugger, my request from python works. I just need to write this whole line in Python proper way. That may be difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
w = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Exactly. That was the problem. I manage to solve this with some documentation help some time ago, but thank you very much for your help Andrey.